# How to show Activity Indicator in UI, while creating file Using File Manger

Tags: ios, swift, mobile-application

I am downloading files (.pdf, .JPG, .PNG etc.) from remote server. "fullFileURLString" is provide file Path URL in String.

When user click on filename from collection view, I need to give option of saving files in user's own device. For That i am using UIDocumentInteractionController(). I am planing to give this functionality to users.

This functionality is working properly. This process take some times to do it. I want to show Activity Indicator while this process is happening. But Activity Indicator is not animating or not displaying on view.

**How to show Activity Indicator when this process is happening & hide activity indicator when documentInteractionController present?**

I had try below code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:"showUplodedMediaCellCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! showUplodedMediaCellCollectionViewCell;
        if let bytes = Memory().deviceRemainingFreeSpaceInBytes() {
            let twoHundresMb:Int64 = 283115520
            if bytes < twoHundresMb {
                Alert.showAlertView(on: self, message: "There is not enough available storage to download.")
            }
            else {
                let activityIndicatior:UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
                activityIndicatior.center = self.view.center
                activityIndicatior.hidesWhenStopped = true
                activityIndicatior.style = .gray
                view.addSubview(activityIndicatior)
                activityIndicatior.startAnimating()
                let mediaDetails = MediaFiles?[indexPath.row]
                if let path = mediaDetails?.folderPath {
                    if let Filename = mediaDetails?.name {
                     let fullFileURLString = "\(baseURL)"+"\(path)"+"\(Filename)"
                        if let FileUrl = URL(string: fullFileURLString) {
                            let Filedata = try? Data(contentsOf: FileUrl)
                            let documentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
                            let documentDirectoryPath2 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
                            let documentDirectoryPathURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectoryPath)

                            if let pathComponent = documentDirectoryPathURL.appendingPathComponent(Filename) {
                                let fileManager = FileManager.default
                                let filePath = pathComponent.path
                                if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
                                    print("Already Have:",Filename)
                                }
                                else {
                                    print("No available",Filename)
                                    let fileManager = FileManager.default
                                    let fileManagerPath = documentDirectoryPath2.appendingPathComponent(Filename)
                                    fileManager.createFile(atPath: fileManagerPath, contents: Filedata, attributes: nil)
                                    print("path:- \(fileManagerPath)")
                                }
                            }

                            let destinationPath = documentDirectoryPath2.appendingPathComponent(Filename)
                            let destinationURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: destinationPath)
                            let dowanloadedMediaDocumentDirectoryPathURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectoryPath)

                            if let pathComponent = dowanloadedMediaDocumentDirectoryPathURL.appendingPathComponent(Filename) {
                                let fileManager = FileManager.default
                                let filePath = pathComponent.path
                                if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
                                    activityIndicatior.stopAnimating()
                                    var documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController()
                                    documentInteractionController.url = destinationURL
                                    if !documentInteractionController.presentOpenInMenu(from: cell.bounds, in: view, animated: true) {
                                        print("You don't have an app installed that can handle ePub files.")

                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    Alert.showAlertView(on: self, message: "Unable to download file from remote server.")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
             }
        }
        else {
            Alert.showAlertView(on: self, message: "There is not enough available storage to download.")
        }
    }
```

I expect the ActivityIndicator will animating until documentInteractionController will not present.

Comment: Try to comment out all the code after `startAnimating()`, can you see the activityIndicator now?

Comment: @TalCohen Yes, If i remove or comment code below startAnimating().

Comment: I would suggest putting all this code after `startAnimating()` in a background thread, and present the `UIDocumentInteractionController` on the main thread.

Comment: @TalCohen Can you share some code ?

Comment: It's difficult the get into your code, but I'll share some code that may explain it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put all the downloading file process in a background thread.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Some code here

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        activityIndicatior.startAnimating()
    }

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {  
        // Download file or perform expensive task

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    }
}
```

Split your code into functions with a single responsibility, it will make your code easier to debug.